# Handling recursion limit in transcendental equations

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

Can anyone tell how do I solve these equations that have a recursion relation?

```
a = u Exp[-v] + v Exp[u];
v = a Exp[-v]+ u;
u = a Exp[-u]+ v;
```

I wish to update `a`first with an initial value of `v=v0`,`x=x0`, after I plug in `a` to `v` and `u` I get recursion in my equations

```
$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of...
```

Can someone advice how to solve this problem?

Comment: I would isolate `a`i.e. `a=u*Exp[-v]+v*Exp[u], a=(v-u)*Exp[v], a=-(v-u)*Exp[u]`. Comparing the last two equations `(v-u)Exp[u]=-(v-u)Exp[v]` implying `(v-u)=0` since Exp is always positive. This means `a=0` is the only possible value of `a`. Then solving `a=0=u*Exp[-u]+u*Exp[u]` means `u` must be zero. So `{a,v,u}={0,0,0}` is the only solution. It is also obvious if you look at a 3D plot of the surfaces defining `a` from the three equations.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Did you know that `Exp[I Pi]==-1`?

Comment: @Artes, yes. I assumed a,u,v are real. Though admittedly that's not mentioned in OP's post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be done as below.

```
Clear[u, v, a];
u[0] = u0;
v[0] = v0;
a[0] = a0;
a[n_] := a[n] = u[n - 1] Exp[-v[n - 1]] + v[n - 1] Exp[u[n - 1]];
v[n_] := v[n] = a[n - 1] Exp[-v[n - 1]] + u[n - 1]
u[n_] := u[n] = a[n - 1] Exp[-u[n - 1]] + v[n - 1];
```

Example:

```
In[639]:= u[3]

(* Out[639]= 
a0 E^-u0 + v0 + E^(-a0 E^-v0 - u0) (E^-v0 u0 + E^u0 v0) + 
 E^(-a0 E^-v0 - u0 - 
   E^(-a0 E^-u0 - v0) (E^-v0 u0 + E^u0 v0)) (E^(
     a0 E^-u0 + v0) (a0 E^-v0 + u0) + 
    E^(-a0 E^-v0 - u0) (a0 E^-u0 + v0)) *)
```

Comment: `RecurrenceTable[]` is another possibility: `RecurrenceTable[{a[n] == u[n - 1] Exp[-v[n - 1]] + v[n - 1] Exp[u[n - 1]], v[n] == a[n - 1] Exp[-v[n - 1]] + u[n - 1], u[n] == a[n - 1] Exp[-u[n - 1]] + v[n - 1], a[0] == a0, v[0] == v0, u[0] == u0}, {a, v, u}, {n, 3, 3}]`